# Редактор имени аудио в телеграм

Tags: python, aiogram, telegram

Подскажите как нужно реализовать изменение названия аудио файла, который пользователь будет пересылать в бот.
Если возможно то подскажите кодом пожалуйста. Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь мог переслать в мой бот аудио файл и у него появлялась возможность присвоить новое имя к аудио файлу.

Comment: Вам нужен алгоритм?

Comment: Я не уверен, но, мне кажется, это сделать невозможно. Только если бот скачивает файл, редактирует название и отправляет обратно. Вы это хотите реализовать?